# Python 3.5.2 Download Link

Tags: python, python-3.5, download

Is there a download link to python version 3.5.2?

Clicking the download link next to the 3.5.2 release here
https://www.python.org/downloads/

sends me here

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/

But nothing for the download comes up.

Where as if I download 3.6.0 using the big yellow button the download begins right away and no page transfer occurs either.

How do I download it?

EDIT: Upon downloading I apparently have a version installed and no matter modify or uninstall it says "No Python 3.5 installation was detected." Upon repairing it says I need administrator privileges, even though I am using an administrator account to download this.

Comment: Did you try scrolling down the page? Clicking on the file that corresponds to your platform?

Comment: I have window vista 32bit I don't know what corresponds to the right file and how to find out.

Comment: Why not try one of the non-64 bit Windows versions and see how it goes? Or get the equivalent to whichever 3.6 was downloading by default. Or just *use 3.6?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloads are found under 'Files' on the bottom of the page.

`x86` means 32 bit. `x86-64` is 64 bit.